# rvm installation on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-20.04

I have runned the following commands on ubuntu sudo apt-get install software-properties-common, sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm,sudo apt-get update,sudo apt-get install rvm, source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh, curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flatiron-school/dotfiles/master/rvm-shell-script >> ~/.bashrc but when i run rvm it says Command 'rvm' not found, but there are 19 similar ones. how can i solve this

I have tried the following commands on ubuntu sudo apt-get install software-properties-common, sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm,sudo apt-get update,sudo apt-get install rvm, source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh, curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flatiron-school/dotfiles/master/rvm-shell-script >> ~/.bashrc but when i run rvm it says Command 'rvm' not found, but there are 19 similar ones. how can i solve this